# How to decode this information from strace output

Tags: c, go, audit, strace, netlink

I wrote  a small go script and traced it using strace
though this script, I am trying to fetch audit messages from kernel using netlink protocol, just like like auditd.

Following is the strace output on my go script- http://paste.ubuntu.com/8272760/

I am trying to find the argument that auditd provide to the sendto function.
When I run strace on auditd I get following output

```
sendto(3, "\20\0\0\0\350\3\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 16
```

And when I strace my go file I get the following output.
I am looking to decode the second argument of this statement

```
sendto(3, "\21\0\0\0\350\3\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t", 17, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 17
```

To be specific

```
"\21\0\0\0\350\3\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t"
```

Now I want to convert this to string or bytes array, is there any way to convert this to string or byte array?

In my actual go code this argument is a byte array.

https://github.com/mozilla/Audit-Go/blob/testing/netlink_old.go#L58

Comment: Hrm: it looks like `wb` in your source code already *is* a `[]byte`, so I don't understand the question as posed, or why strace is involved. (What's happening that makes `strace` necessary rather than relying on instrumentation of the Go code?)

Comment: Separately, [it's conventional to avoid dot imports](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Import_Dot) like the `. "syscall".

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the problem is that you're dealing with strace output that's *not* all from your code, and you're not sure how to parse it. What I have is probably not the best-practice way to do it, but I think JavaScript uses close enough to the same quoting rules you can just drop the string into a script: http://jsfiddle.net/2tukw37o/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding of your problem is you try to compare what auditd sends to what your program sends by comparing strace output, and you have issues to convert the string provided by strace into a Go []byte datatype.

The strace output follows the GNU C representation of string literal, whose characters can be escaped as follows:

```
\\ Backslash character. 
\? Question mark character.
\' Single quotation mark. 
\" Double quotation mark. 
\a Audible alert. 
\b Backspace character. 
\e <ESC> character. (This is a GNU extension.) 
\f Form feed. 
\n Newline character. 
\r Carriage return. 
\t Horizontal tab. 
\v Vertical tab.
\o, \oo, \ooo Octal number.
\xh, \xhh, \xhhh, ... Hexadecimal number.
```

Note that the number of octal or hex digits can be variable. In Go, characters can also be escaped but the rules are different - see http://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals

In particular, the octal values are systematically on 3 digits to avoid any ambiguity. To declare a []byte with such a sequence of characters, you will have to write something like this:

```
// In strace, it was "\21\0\0\0\350\3\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t"
wb := []byte("\021\000\000\000\350\003\005\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\t")
```

Note that the -x option in strace will use fixed-length hex encoding for non-printable characters,  which makes the direct usage of these strings easier in a Go program. The -xx option will output hex encoded bytes even for printable characters, which makes it even easier IMO.

Anyway, it is not necessarily a good style (or even a good idea) to use literal strings to initialize []byte. Strings are for UTF-8 characters, not for binary data.

Answer (score 7):

If you want `strace` to print hexadecimal string instead ASCII and escaped sequence, use `-x` or `-xx`, consult man for more details.

Answer (score 6):

> `\21\0\0\0\350\3\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t`

These are character escape sequences as defined in the `ANSI X3.159-1989` (aka [`ANSI C89`](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard), check this [PDF file](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)). You can [find](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17014835/55075) the official draft pages at [port70.net](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/).

Here is a short brief found in [`man printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf):

- `\a`      Write a `<bell>` character.
- `\b`      Write a `<backspace>` character.
- `\c`      Ignore remaining characters in this string.
- `\e`      Write a `<escape>` character.
- `\f`      Write a `<form-feed>` character.
- `\r`      Write a `<carriage return>` character.
- `\n`      Write a `<new-line>` character.
- `\t`      Write a `<tab>` character.
- `\v`      Write a `<vertical tab>` character.
- `\'`      Write a `<single quote>` character.
- `\"`      Write a `<double quote>` character.
- `\\`      Write a backslash character.
- `\num`, `\0num`   Write an 8-bit character whose ASCII value is the 1-, 2-, or 3-digit octal number.

To interpret these characters as string, you can use `printf`, e.g. command in shell:

```
printf "%b" "\21\0\0\0\350\3\5\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t"
```

For more parsing examples, check: [How to parse strace in shell into plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36557017/55075)

Comment: Doesn't work correctly for me. E.g. `\0374` gets decoded as `fc` by `printf`, while in reality it's `1f34`

Comment: It works if you remove the "%b". As the man of printf explains 
_%b     ARGUMENT as a string with '\' escapes interpreted, except that octal escapes are of the form \0 or \0NNN_  
`$ printf  "\0374" | xxd -g 1
00000000: 1f 34 `