# Why is struct addrinfo defined only if __USE_XOPEN2K is defined?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I'm reading the man page for [getaddrinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) and trying to follow the example code, but it doesn't compile:

```
// test.c
#include <netdb.h>

void f() {
    struct addrinfo t;
}
```

Both with clang:

```
$ clang -std=c11 test.c
test.c:10:21: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct addrinfo'
    struct addrinfo t;
                    ^
test.c:10:12: note: forward declaration of 'struct addrinfo'
    struct addrinfo t;
           ^
1 error generated.
```

and gcc:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 test.c
test.c: In function ‘f’:
test.c:10:21: error: storage size of ‘t’ isn’t known
     struct addrinfo t;
                     ^
```

After some digging I found that the [glibc headers](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/3164bf09f529754216eebfa66a5c32ce84eaec25/resolv/netdb.h#L564-L577) have a preprocessor directive that "protects" (is this the right term?) the `struct` from being defined, so I'm wondering:

- Why does glibc uses `#ifdef __USE_XOPEN2K` and [others don't](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libinfo/Libinfo-406.17/lookup.subproj/netdb.h)? what is used for? why did it change from [__USE_POSIX](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/commit/8737be806407be51f046b358d8824c4c968912de)?
- Why clang and gcc define `__USE_XOPEN2K` with `-std=gnu89`, `-std=gnu90`, `-std=gnu99` but not with `-ansi`, `-std=c89`, `-std=c90`, `-std=c99` and `-std=c11`?
- What should I use to not get the error? Use `-std=gnuXX` or use `#define __USE_XOPEN2K`?

Comment: I wonder this too, in my case because it prevents the barrier in pthreads from being defined.

Comment: Names such as `__USE_XOPEN2K` and `__USE_POSIX` are handled by the implementation and you should not attempt to set them yourself directly.  You should set `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` — which have defined effects, including exposing declarations such as `struct addrinfo`.  Using `-std=gnu11` or similar enables all those and (potentially) extra GNU extensions.  In some ways, it is simpler.

Answer (score 20):

Short answer, if you are using glibc with APIs that are not part of the standard C (anything UNIX related) just use the `-std=gnuXX` — this will enable a [couple of features in the glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/0a1f1e78fbdfaf2c01e9c2368023b2533e7136cf/include/features.h#L154-L175). [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros)

---

Long answer:

This is a complex matter, the C programming language and the Unix OSs are old and have a lot of baggage; this is my try at understanding all of this.

There is a C programming language. The language appeared in the year 1972 but it was not standardized until 1989, when the first ANSI C was ratified. Currently there are these specifications of the C programming language:

- **1989** Known as the *ANSI C* or *C89* [X3.159-1989].
- **1990** Known as the *ISO C* or *C90* [ISO/IEC 9899:1990]
- **1995** Known as the *AMD1* or *C94* or *C95* [ISO/IEC 9899:1990/AMD 1:1995]
- **1999** Known as the *C99* [ISO/IEC 9899:1999]
- **2011** Known as the *C11* or *C1X* [ISO/IEC 9899:2011]

The C standard has a really [limited scope](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#1), it provides the syntax, semantics, and [some library headers and functions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2). The specifications ([c99](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.10.8) and [c11](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8)) contained some predefined macros that the compiler should expose, these macros are used to indicate conformance to the standard, so that the program can use new features that older specifications didn't have, but there is no macro that the source code could use to remove features.

Besides the C programming language specification there are a couple of [UNIX specifications](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/ch17s02.html#ftn.id2995003). Trying to make a [long story](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/writings/taoup/html/ch02s01.html) and convoluted history short, ignoring problems with the trademark and legalese:

At the beginning UNIX did not have a specification and it's source was sort of illegally copied and modified, the result is a [long list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V#/media/File:Unix_history-simple.svg) of UNIX variants, some of which invented incompatible or conflicting APIs, like BSD's tty socket and SVR3 termio. After some time working groups were formed to standardize the OS:

- **1983** The *Uniforum* also know as */usr/group* created the first standardization named as *core UNIX System*
- **1985** *AT&T* had the *System V Interface Definition* or *SVID*
- **1984** The *The Open Group* also know as *X/Open* created the *X/Open Portability Guide* or *XPG*,
- **1985** The *IEEE 1003* group was created, they created the *POSIX* standard

The work of these groups can be describe with this incomplete timeline:

- **1983** *Uniforum* created *core UNIX System* or *UDS 83* [Uniforum 1983 Draft Standard]
- **1985** *SVID* superseded *UDS 83*
- **1985** *XPG1* with APIs from *SVR2* and *4.2BSD* (POSIX plus sockets)
- **1987,1990,1992** *XPG2*, *XPG3*, and *XPG4*
- **1988 - 1995** The first documents that compose the *POSIX* standard (*1003.1*, 1003.2*, and *1003.4*)
- **1997** [SUSv2](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/)
- **2004** *POSIX:2004* or [SUSv3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/), an updated of the 2001 version
  [IEEE Std 1003.1-2004]
- **2008** *POSIX:2008* [IEEE Std 1003.1-2008]

The acronyms are:

- *SUS* refers to **Single UNIX Specification**
- *XPG* refers to **X/Open Portability Guides**
- *POSIX* refers to **Portable Operating System Interface**

Okay, so now GCC and the glibc need to compile and link against any C program developed with any of these standards in mind, the [glibc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros) says:

> If you compile your programs using ‘`gcc -ansi`’, you get only the ISO C library features, unless you explicitly request additional features by defining one or more of the feature macros [...]. You should define these macros by using ‘`#define`’ preprocessor directives at the top of your source code files. These directives must come before any #include of a system header file [...]. This system exists to allow the library to conform to multiple standards.

GCC's docs about [language's dialects](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) states the following:

> `-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c90` [...]. This turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with **ISO C90** (when compiling C code), such as the asm and typeof keywords, and predefined macros such as unix and vax that identify the type of system you are using. `-std=‘c89’` is the same as `-ansi` for C code.

Also the docs about [standard libraries](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standard-Libraries.html#Standard-Libraries):

> If you need a standard-compliant library, then you need to find one, as GCC does not provide one. The GNU C library (called glibc) provides ISO C, POSIX, BSD, SystemV and X/Open compatibility for GNU/Linux and HURD-based GNU systems;

Useful links:

- [GCC Standards](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)
- [iso-9899 wiki](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/The_Standard)
- SO: [Where can I find the C89/C90 standards in PDF format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014835/where-can-i-find-the-c89-c90-standards-in-pdf-format)

Comment: Lots of good information here.  What you didn't mention that you can select which version of POSIX, or the X/Open (SUS) specification, using — for example — `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` (for the SUS corresponding to POSIX 2008), or `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809` (for POSIX 2008).  In general, `_XOPEN_SOURCE 700` is loosely equivalent to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`; `_XOPEN_SOURCE 600` is loosely equivalent to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L`; and
`_XOPEN_SOURCE 500` is loosely equivalent to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L`.

Comment: For VS Code Intellisense to accept this code under the GNU standard, run the command C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI) and select the gnu17 standard from the C standard option.