# Why does getpagesize() return an int?

Tags: c, unix, memory-management, int, system-calls

Why does the syscall `getpagesize()` return an `int` and not an `unsigned int` or a `size_t`?

Prototype and short description below:

```
GETPAGESIZE(2)                                                             
    NAME
           getpagesize - get memory page size
    SYNOPSIS
           #include <unistd.h>
           int getpagesize(void);
```

Comment: Most likely for similar *"reasons"* as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719737/why-does-fgets-accept-an-int-instead-of-a-size-t), if I had to guess [?]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`int` was probably sufficient when it was invented. But it's no longer an issue because the
`getpagesize()` has been removed from POSIX standard since 2001 and has been superseded by `sysconf()`.
You should use `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`.

[`getpagesize()` returning an int was one of the major reasons why it was removed:](http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/datasize.html)

> getpagesize
>
> The getpagesize( ) function returns the current page size. It is equivalent to sysconf (_SC_PAGE_SIZE) and sysconf (_SC_PAGESIZE). **This interface, returning an int, may have problems representing appropriate values in the future.** Also the behaviour is not specified for this interface on systems that support variable size pages. On variable page size systems, a page can be extremely large (theoretically, up to the size of memory). This allows very efficient address translations for large segments of memory that have common page attributes. **A note about this has been added to Application Usage, and the interface marked Legacy, with the recommendation that applications should use the sysconf() interface instead.**

(emphasis mine).