# What happens when a C programme is terminated without exit or abort function that means normally?

Tags: c, exit, abort

As we know that:-

> `exit()` performs following operations.
>
> - Flushes unwritten buffered data.
> - Closes all open files.
> - Removes temporary files.
> - Returns an integer exit status to the operating system.

And

> `abort()` may not close opened files. It may also not delete
> temporary files and may not flush stream buffer. Also, it does not
> call functions registered with atexit().

Source:- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-exit-abort-and-assert/

So my question is What happens when a program terminates without these two functions (normally)?

I hope you got my question...

Answer (score 0):

According to the C11 standard (well, the n1570 draft linked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014835/where-can-one-find-the-c89-c90-standards-in-pdf-format)), Section 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination states that the behavior is unspecified.

Quoting the C11 draft:

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with
> int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent
> to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main
> function as its argument;11) reaching the } that terminates the main
> function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible
> with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is
> unspecified.

As far as I know, this behavior has been the same since pretty much the inception of C.

If you're ever faced with this situation, it's better to treat this scenario as a bug that needs fixing, unless you're willing to dive into whatever is the behavior specified by your compiler/toolchain/framework.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. The part I think that answers the question (as I read it) is that "a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function ..." Returning a type that's not compatible with int doesn't seem to be relevant to the question as far as I can see.

Comment: My take is that a C program is either terminated with a call to `exit()`, an explicit `return` from `main`, or its control flow just drops from `main` without an explicit call to either `exit()` or `return`.  The reference I've provided explains the latter case, which is the only possibility left open by the question..

Comment: OK, but the standard text that you've quoted says that dropping off the end of main is the same a returning 0. That's not a bug or unspecified behavior.

Comment: @PaulHankin you might be right here.  The semicolon bundled with the ref led me to read the paragraph as it all referred to the explicit call to `exit()`, leading me to interpret it as anything that does't involve explicit returns or exits is unspecified.

Comment: Claiming the behaviour is unspecified is wrong.  The first sentence of the quote specifies the behavior precisely.  It's only if the return type of `main()` is not compatible with `int` that there is unspecified behaviour.  The quote is good.  The interpretation is wrong.