# Changing the value of a constant

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I thought that the `&` operator wouldn't work for constants because I thought their invokations are replaced with their values at compile time like with macros and that they're rvalues. I wrote this test and the output suprised me.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    const int a=1;
    *(int*)&a=2;
    printf("%i%i",a,*&a);
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs 12. I expected it to be 11. Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: If you invoke undefined behaviour by bludgeoning the compiler into accepting your code with casts, you get what you get.  If you removed the cast, the code would not compile.

Comment: Surely you expected `22`? It outputs `11` without that line.

Comment: Actually no, I thought that it would behave like the address is somehow read-only.

Comment: On a side note, there are no extra taxes or fees for using whitespace in your program and its output.  Why not make it easier on yourself, and readers of this question, by using `printf("%i %i",a,*&a);`?

Comment: In this situation it doesn't matter one way or the other because not both of the numbers have more than one digit.

Comment: @markoj Suit yourself.  I, at least, found it confusing and annoying.

Comment: If I make the constant `register`, the code wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It outputs 12. I expected it to be 11.

Incorrect expectations.

---

Casting a pointer to `const` data to a pointer to non-`const` data is OK - if the resulting pointer is not used to write data.

```
const int a=1;
(int*)&a; // OK
```

Attempting to write via a pointer that originated as a pointer to `const` data is *undefined behavior*  (UB).  Don't code like that.  Anything may happen.

```
*(int*)&a = ... // Not OK
```

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. C17dr § 6.7.3 7

Comment: I think that taking a `&` of a constant shouldn't be allowed because I think it's not needed unless you want to change its value. Is there a compiler that doesn't allow that?

Comment: Care to add a reference to your UB claim? I guess it'd improve the answer overall

Comment: @markoj "... because I think it's not needed unless you want to change its value" is incorrect. Some code uses/returns pointers to the object and not the object itself with always writing the object.

Comment: @WilkMaia Do you have access to the C spec?

Comment: @WilkMaia Search for "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, yep. I didn't mean it for my benefit. It was a suggestion to improve the answer :)

Comment: FYI if you wanna link ~the spec~ some drafts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17015061/2853886

Comment: You're right, @chux-ReinstateMonica. For example, when using a number of an optional size a function can require `void*` and `size_t` instead. An equivalent situation happened to me some time ago. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the significance of the `volatile` keyword below.

Two identical functions, except that TrialB has keyword volatile, and TrialA does not.

`TrialA` outputs `11`, because the compiler believes that variable `a` is const and cannot change.

`TrialB` outputs `22`, because despite being declared `const`, the variable is also `volatile` and therefore needs to be re-examined on every use.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void TrialA(void)
{
    const int a=1;
    *(int*)&a=2;   // I expected a Warning on this line!
                   // Along the lines of "incompatible typecast from "const int*" to "int*"
                   // But surprisingly, I do not see such a warning.
    printf("%i%i\n",a,*&a);
}

void TrialB(void)
{
    volatile const int a=1;
    *(int*)&a=2;
    printf("%i%i\n",a,*&a);
}


int main(void){
    TrialA();
    TrialB();
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5536KB
11
22
```

Comment: I also thought that there would be a warning because it happends when I do pointer types typecast.

Comment: _// I expected a Warning on this line!_ Compile with `-Wcast-qual` to get the warning